# Appium : xPath without text not identifying the object

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-java

Issue description: Using xpath with text description works fine, but using xpath having id is not working.

*[Sensitive parts being masked in picture and code]*

I'm trying to perform a mock project on a mobile app with latest appium version.
Having following dependency in my pom file

java-client: 8.1.1 |
selenium-java: 4.2.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the screen shot of the app, where i'm trying to identify text. "Hey Ram,"

[image]

Using xpath option in appium studio,i'm finding both the xpath.

1. Copy Unique Xpath ==> //*[@text='Hey Ram,']
2. Copy Unique Xpath (skip text) ==> //*[@id='dialog_fr_tv_title']

[image]

I'm identifying the the text using appium inspector filter and it clearly identifying uniquely.

1. Using option Copy Unique Xpath (xpath = //*[@text='Hey Ram,'])

[image]

2. Using option Copy Unique Xpath (skip text)  (xpath= //*[@id='dialog_fr_tv_title'])

[image]

This clearly shows, both xpath one with text, and another with id is clearly identifying the element uniquely.

I have written the following Java code, where i try to extract the text and print the value.

```
package basics;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.SupportsLegacyAppManagement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class SimpleAppiumClass {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "null", "deprecation" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AppiumDriver driver=null;
        
        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("udid", "d278263c");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
        caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xx.vxx.xxxxxx");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.xx.vxx.xxxxxx.view.activity.SVSplashScreenActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        
        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement elementId = driver.findElement(By.id("dialog_fr_tv_title"));
            System.out.println("id text: "+elementId.getText());
            WebElement elementTextXpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Hey Ram,']"));
            System.out.println("using text(xpath)=: "+elementTextXpath.getText());
            //*[@text='Hey Ram,']
            WebElement elementIdXpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dialog_fr_tv_title']"));
            System.out.println("using id(xpath)=: "+elementIdXpath.getText());
            
            ((SupportsLegacyAppManagement) driver).closeApp(); 


            
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            ((SupportsLegacyAppManagement) driver).closeApp(); 
        }
        
        System.out.println("---End of execution---"); 
    }
}
```

**First time**, i'm using By.id [driver.findElement(By.id("dialog_fr_tv_title"))] print me "Hey Ram," text as expected.

**Second time**, using By.xpath [driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Hey Ram,']"))] print me also 'Hey Ram?," text as expected. This time xpath is written using text option.

**Thrid time**, using By.xpath [driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dialog_fr_tv_title']"))] throws me error "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: "

Not only for this element, trying to give xpath for button "Continue with mobile number" throws same error.

For button without text: //*[@id='dialog_fr_mobile_btn'] --> **throws error**

For buttom with text: //*[@text='Continue with Mobile Number'] --> **works fine.**

Execution logs

```
id text: Hey Ram,
using text(xpath)=: Hey Ram,
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://selenium.dev/exceptions/#no_such_element
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-0LQSGR9A', ip: '172.31.98.220', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [f30292c6-4f04-4d4f-939c-a8d98c801efb, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id='dialog_fr_tv_title']}]
Capabilities {appium:appActivity: com.tv.v18.viola.view.activ..., appium:appPackage: com.tv.v18.viola, appium:automationName: UiAutomator2, appium:databaseEnabled: false, appium:desired: {appActivity: com.tv.v18.viola.view.activ..., appPackage: com.tv.v18.viola, automationName: UiAutomator2, noReset: true, platformName: android, platformVersion: 11, udid: d278263c}, appium:deviceApiLevel: 28, appium:deviceManufacturer: OnePlus, appium:deviceModel: ONEPLUS A5000, appium:deviceName: d278263c, appium:deviceScreenDensity: 380, appium:deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, appium:deviceUDID: d278263c, appium:javascriptEnabled: true, appium:locationContextEnabled: false, appium:networkConnectionEnabled: true, appium:noReset: true, appium:pixelRatio: 2.375, appium:platformVersion: 9, appium:statBarHeight: 57, appium:takesScreenshot: true, appium:udid: d278263c, appium:viewportRect: {height: 1863, left: 0, top: 57, width: 1080}, appium:warnings: {}, appium:webStorageEnabled: false, platformName: ANDROID}
Session ID: f30292c6-4f04-4d4f-939c-a8d98c801efb
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:387)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:379)
    at basics.SimpleAppiumClass.main(SimpleAppiumClass.java:40)
```

Let me know if anything I missed or issue with latest version (known issue), any work around. Using text in some scenario will not be good thing if I try to code.

Regards,
Ramkumar

Comment: Kind of long stretch but have you tried `//*[@resource-id='dialog_fr_mobile_btn']` instead of just `@id`?

Comment: @drunkencheetah ->  Using resource-id as xpath is working. But not working with @id=dialog_fr_tv_title

WebElement elementIdXpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.tv.v18.viola:id/dialog_fr_tv_title']"));
System.out.println("using id(xpath)=: "+elementIdXpath.getText());

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is because for native elements the selector strategy on Android is `resource-id`, you can refer to the information [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/find-elements/index.html#selector-strategies). Also I haven't done this in a while but I think you can use `resource-id` without providing the package name :)

Comment: WebElement elementIdXpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='dialog_fr_tv_title']"));
System.out.println("using id(xpath)=: "+elementIdXpath.getText());

Only with package name[com.tv.v18.viola:id/dialog_fr_tv_title] it works. Without package name [dialog_fr_tv_title] it throws NoSuchElementException

Comment: I don't know that ObjectSpy you are using but I did a quick check with Appium Inspector on the Android Settings app and for me both `id` and `resource-id` are the same and they both contain the package name. I would suggest you just go with `resource-id` because this is what the Appium documentation states should be used for native selector